# Is there a difference between these 2 ways of removing an event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

Is there a difference here?

```
Button1.Click -= new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

and

```
Button1.Click -= Button1_Click;
```

The second method doesn't seem to work for me but I've seen it used when Google-ing 'how to remove an event handler'. **Edit:** Actually neither are working for me, even so *should* either work interchangeably?

**Update:**

The reason these didn't appear to work for me is because I had AutoPostBack=true on my controls. I wasn't setting breakpoints to see if the events were called, I just watched the browser to see if it refreshed (meaning a post-back).

Comment: @MarkByers No actually, I've updated my question to show this. Very astute of you!

Comment: Sounds like the `Button1_Click` signature might be wrong. Did the code work for adding them?

Comment: @Enigmativity I added the event handlers in the markup in the front-end of my aspx page so there was no problem there. I've updated my question to explain the mistake I made in assuming this code wasn't working when it was something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those two pieces of code are the same. The second syntax (called "method group conversion") was a new feature added in C# 2.0.

Comment: I think that the first one is kind of missleading. It doesn't feel like i remove the existing one. Possibly that alot of beginners find that irritating.

Comment: @dowhilefor I don't really consider myself a beginner anymore but still really dislike the first syntax.  Removing a reference to an object from a list because I attempt to remove a different object that happens to have the same value still seems like a hack.

Comment: @Yaur sorry i wasn't implying that you were a beginner, it was just a guess that it might be irritating to other people learning the language. But i agree, i don't think its obvious for anyone. To be honest, i had to look it up what exactly happens there a couple of month ago, because i wasn't sure anymore aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, no.  There is no difference between the two.  As to your issue about neither working, if this is an ASP.NET app, you may want to disable auto event wireup in the aspx page.